# Can Random Forest be considered as a Frequentist method?

Tags: bayesian, random-forest, frequentist

I am very new to machine learning so I apologize if this is a silly or even a repetitive question. I am running a **Random forest** model in R and was just wondering whether this is a frequentist method and why. I have looked everywhere but still haven't found a proper full answer. One of the sources I was looking at, [Are random forests Bayesian?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85778/are-random-forests-bayesian).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Greg Snow's answer in the linked thread settles it quite nicely. I would suggest looking into understanding how bootstrap works. In short, "*yes, it is frequentist; for example, no prior prior is explicitly defined*", but that is a somewhat hammy statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a *machine learning algorithm*, it doesn't have to belong to either of those categories. Frequentist and Bayesian *statistics* is the distinction based on how probabilities are interpreted. Machine Learning algorithms are about finding patterns in the data and making predictions based on the learned patterns. Frequentist vs Bayesian is about inference about probabilities, while in machine learning you care only about making predictions, not about correctly estimating the probabilities (indeed, probabilities returned by machine learning algorithms are often [not well callibrated](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html)).

For being able to make such distinction for machine learning model, you would need to define it in probabilistic terms, and for a Bayesian model, you would need to be able to provide priors for the parameters, as noticed in the answer to the thread you linked.

Comment: Both answers are very helpful and have clarified a lot of things for me. Thank you heaps!